# JQuery doesn't seem to work for autocomplete (Bootstrap + Django Website)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web

I'm simply trying to autocomplete using JQuery but there's no change autocomplete suggestions. I'm not calling back, just using local list for autocomplete. I'have tried inspect element to monitor network but it doesn't do anything. No changes as I complete the text. Here's the required code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {

var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC",
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Clojure",
  "COBOL",
  "ColdFusion",
  "Erlang",
  "Fortran",
  "Groovy",
  "Haskell",
  "Java",
  "JavaScript",
  "Lisp",
  "Perl",
  "PHP",
  "Python",
  "Ruby",
  "Scala",
  "Scheme"
];
  $("#vote").autocomplete({
    minLength:3,
    source: availableTags
  });
});

</script>
```

My includes :

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/
    GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="
    sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/
    JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And my input:

```
  <div class="ui-widget">
     <input id="vote" type="text" name="vote"/>
  </div>
```

It doesn't do anything. Neither throwing out any error so that I can fix. I'm new to this and after scratching my head for 2 days asked here for help.

Comment: `jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js` Are you sure the slim version is enough to support autocomplete? it's missing quite a few important features.

Comment: @KevinB Thank you so much I made few changes with Jquery imports and the problem was this only. However I'm clueless why my question was downvoted ? Can you help me figure it out so that I can in future improve while asking questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems
1) autocomplete is a feature of JqueryUI - you need a reference to that library as well..see below

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

2) as noted in the comment, "jquery slim" is missing some components you'll need for JQueryUI.  If you'll get the non-slimmed version, your code should start working

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the answer. I got my autocomplete run. I'm accepting your answer. Thanks again.